# xpages gridx jsonREST and query/search

Tags: xpages, dojo.gridx, gridx

I have been following the excellent 'Dojo Grids in XPages' by Brad Balassaitis - https://xcellerant.net/dojo-grids-in-xpages/

I have an XPage with a jsonREST service referencing a Notes View, and the options described in Part 10 - Dojo data grid searching and filtering.

So it all works very well, I can make a choice in the ComboBox, and the Grid reloads showing the results of the jsonREST Service Search.

I now want to do the same thing with gridx; again Brad has an excellent series on this - https://xcellerant.net/gridx-in-xpages/

However, he does not cover doing a jsonREST search and reloads of the gridx.

I have been trying to replicate the techniques from the Data Grid version, but with no success. I am not even sure if I should be directly running a jsonREST Search, and then refreshing the grid, or use the grid.query method. I am finding very little good documentation, and any related articles do not seem to help me much. I am stuck now really.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steven's code helped me to find an answer that worked for me.  All of the filter/gridx store query/JSON Rest update/refresh gridx/gridx filterSetupQuery attempts I made failed miserably.  What worked for me was to use the `?search=` option in the URL when generating the store:

```
var store = JsonRest({idProperty:'@entryid', target:'xpViewQBuster.xsp/jsonREST' + strSearch});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using gridx with jSONRest and search etc.  I actually had to contract Brad to get it to work LOL as I could not figure it out.  So I feel your pain.

If you have specific questions, I'd be glad to help.  Or ping me on skype steven.rieger

Comment: Thanks Steven.  I was thinking my next step may be to contact Brad directly.  Tried to ping you on Skype, but I can find about 20 steven.rieger's on Skype!  Do you have any information from Brad you can share?

Comment: I'm steven.rieger in Illinois if that helps or srieger@riegergroup.com
I'd be happy to share some code with you.

Comment: Skype contact requested.  I have also emailed you, thanks in advance for your help